# Is there a phrase that means "make your mind less confused"?

Tags: phrase-request

I know for a fact that the word "unconfuse" doesn't exist, and I can't think of any phrase that mean "make your mind less confused", so what are some option. I am thinking of a situation where someone is saying a lot of nonsense and can't think rationally and someone tells him to "make his mind less confused" before saying anything that he may regret.

Answer (score 1):

A few options are:

[Get your head together](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+head+together) or get your head on straight.

Also, [pull it together](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+it+together).

They both basically mean "settle your thoughts/actions and behave appropriately."